# Indeterminate Progress bar for webview in fragment

Tags: java, android, webview, nullpointerexception, android-progressbar

I am trying to show a circular indeterminate loading indicator for a webView however despite reading a load of answers on here, my builds are failing. I get the error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ProgressBar.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference`. I have set up the progress bar in the fragment.xml file like so:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/prgrsbar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress" >
</ProgressBar>
```

and created an empty `progress.xml` file in drawable with this in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</selector>
```

Finally, here is my fragment's `onCreateView` activity code that I am using:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //code here



    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);

    String url = "http://winn-brown.co.uk/shmee/";
    WebView view = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.loadUrl(url);

    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        private ProgressBar prgrsBar;
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            prgrsBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // do your stuff here
            Log.i("message", "website loaded");

        }
    });


    return rootView;
}
```

On this line `private ProgressBar prgrsBar;` it says "Private field 'prgrsBar' is never assigned, despite having the id in the fragment's xml file. Apologies if I am missing something obvious here.

Comment: prgrsBar variable is null .First you initialize it like this way.  ProgressBar bar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.pgrsbar);

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
prgrsBar = (ProgressBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.prgrsbar);
```

below

```
private ProgressBar prgrsBar;
```

Comment: I then get a error 'variable prgrsBar is already defined in the scope'

Comment: ProgressBar prgrsBar = (ProgressBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.prgrsbar);  

Replace above line with your below line

 private ProgressBar prgrsBar;

Comment: Tried that too - same error.

Comment: Can you paste here your whole Fragment code

Comment: http://pastebin.com/3PAuV9w5

Comment: Use only prgrsBar = (ProgressBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.prgrsbar);

Comment: You added   ProgressBar prgrsBar = (ProgressBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.prgrsbar);

that why you are getting error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117583/discussion-between-akshay-panchal-and-dwinnbrown).

Answer (score 0):

You need to get a reference of the progress bar from the xml file after this call in `onCreateView`

`View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);`

Comment: I tried this `ProgressBar prgrsBar = (ProgressBar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.prgrsbar);` but it said variable 'prgrsBar' is never used. Maybe this is because it is outside the webview client?

Comment: where do you use that variable?

Comment: here `private ProgressBar prgrsBar;
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            prgrsBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }`

Comment: Move the `private ProgressBar prgrsBar` to the outer class (it should be a variable of the fragment)